# Require and other file system related functions such as readdir do not function as I would expect they would

Tags: javascript, typescript

Whenever I use `require()` (I can't use import because this is in a `forEach` loop) or `readdir()` (I have run this through `util.promisify`) it doesn't work and throws an error at me.

```js
readdir("./events")
   .then(events => {
       events.forEach(event => {
           const Event = require(`./events/${event}`);
           this.client.on(Event.name, Event.handler);
       })
   })
```

I get the following error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir`

Pretty sure `./` should make it look in the directory the file with the code in is in.

Comment: Is there a file or directory in your ./events directory with the name scandir? If so, then `readdir` seems to be working as expected.

Comment: There's no file called scandir.

Comment: Do any of the files being `require`d have a dependency on the scandir package?

Comment: A good test would be to replace the require and following line with just a console log and verify that it prints out the expected files.  That would verify whether the problem is in a required file or not.